# Como medir a performance de códigos em PHP?

Tags: php, desempenho

Para medir a performance e comparar dois códigos em `javascript`, eu faço da seguinte maneira, no console do navegador:

```js
// Vamos testar o código 1
console.time('teste1');
for (var i = 0; i++ < 10000;) {
    $('#table tr').addClass('destaque');
}
console.timeEnd('teste1');
// teste1: 389.000ms


// Vamos testar o código 2
console.time('teste2');
for (var i = 0; i++ < 10000;) {
    $('#table').find('tr').addClass('destaque');
}
console.timeEnd('teste2');
// teste2: 375.000ms
```

Explicação rápida: basta iniciar um contador em milissegundos, rodar o código que eu quero testar várias vezes (1000, 10000, etc) dentro de um loop e anotar o tempo. Depois é só fazer o mesmo procedimento para o outro código a ser testado e comparar os tempos para ver quem tem o melhor desempenho para o navegador em questão.

Mas e em PHP? Será que o método a seguir é o mais recomendado?

```php
$str = 'teste';
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$time = microtime(1);
$mem = memory_get_usage();

for ($i = 0; $i++ < 100000;) {
    $str = strtr($str, 'e', 'x');
    // Comparar com: $str = str_replace('e', 'x', $str);
    // Comparar com: $str = preg_replace('/e/', 'x', $str);
}

echo 'Tempo: ', 1000 * (microtime(1) - $time), "ms\n";
echo 'Memória: ', (memory_get_usage() - $mem) / (1024 * 1024);
```

Baseado em http://php.dzone.com/articles/5-things-you-should-check-now

Comment: Eu sugiro o Xhprof!
http://br1.php.net/xhprof Dá uma olhada aqui também: http://xhprof.io/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Como todas as respostas (inclusive a pergunta!) já disseram, `microtime` é uma opção para testes mais simples. Porém, análises mais profundas demandam o uso de uma ferramenta de *Profiler*.

Por exemplo, se você tem um determinado algoritmo executando, você não quer saber apenas o tempo total, mas quantas vezes cada função foi chamada e quanto tempo cada uma delas demorou.

Isso permite saber onde estão os maiores "custos" e otimizar onde realmente importa. Segundo a [Lei de Pareto](http://xdebug.org/docs/install), você poderia melhorar o desempenho de 80% da aplicação ajustando 20% dos trechos mais pesados.

Bem, uma das formas de fazer isso é [instalando o xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) no seu PHP e realizando uma análise visual com uma ferramenta como o [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind).  Veja um exemplo do resultado obtido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não conhecia o Webgrind, vai me ajudar bastante neste início de ano em um projeto que preciso otimizar.

Answer (score 14):

A função [`microtime`](http://php.net/microtime) na minha opinião é sim a mais adequada, porém você pode usa-la de uma forma um pouco mais refinada:

```php
$inicio1 = microtime(true);
//Seu primeiro script
$total1 = microtime(true) - $inicio1;
echo 'Tempo de execução do primeiro script: ' . $total1;
```

```php
$inicio2 = microtime(true);
//Seu segundo script
$total2 = microtime(true) - $inicio2;
echo 'Tempo de execução do segundo script: ' . $total2;
```

Com relacão ao `memory_get_usage()` eu também o vejo como a melhor opção, e como ele ja retorna os valores em `Bytes` não vejo por que fazer nada alem do valor final menos inicial, agora se você quer algo mais completo ou até melhor do que isso, acredito que somente utilizando plugins, com o seu próprio PHP acredito que esta seja a melhor forma mesmo...

Answer (score 7):

Pesquisando bastante, percebi que usar [microtime](http://php.net/microtime) serve bem.
Criei uma função para comparar os códigos:

```php
function comparar() {
    $funcoes = func_get_args();
    $vezes = 100000;

    for ($i = 0, $len = count($funcoes); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $time = microtime(1);
        $funcao = $funcoes[$i];

        for ($j = 0; $j++ < $vezes;) {
            $funcao();
        }

        $total = 1000 * (microtime(1) - $time);
        $media = $total / $vezes;

        echo 'Tempo total: ', round($total, 3), "ms\n";
        echo 'Tempo médio: ', round($media, 3), "ms\n\n";
    }
}
```

Então para comparar [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace), [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) e [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace), basta fazer:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

comparar(
    function() {
        str_replace('e', 'x', 'teste');
    },

    function() {
        strtr('teste', 'e', 'x');
    },

    function() {
        preg_replace('/e/', 'x', 'teste');
    }
);
```

O resultado final é algo como:

```
Tempo total: 347.955ms
Tempo médio: 0.003ms

Tempo total: 333.841ms
Tempo médio: 0.003ms

Tempo total: 455.327ms
Tempo médio: 0.005ms
```

### Ver também:

Benchmarks feitos com microtime:
http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: Basicamente, isso não é o mesmo código inserido na pergunta só que dentro de uma function?

Comment: É isso. Percebi que essa solução funciona bem e muitas pessoas usam desse jeito.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma pequena classe para medição de tempo. Talvez seja útil a alguém:

```
class TemporizacaoHelper {

    private $inicio;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->inicio = microtime(true);
    }

    public function iniciar() {
        $this->inicio = microtime(true);
    }

    public function segundos() {
        return microtime(true) - $this->inicio;
    }

    public function tempo() {
        $segs = $this->segundos();
        $dias = floor($segs / 86400);
        $segs -= $dias * 86400;
        $horas = floor($segs / 3600);
        $segs -= $horas * 3600;
        $minutos = floor($segs / 60);
        $segs -= $minutos * 60;
        $microsegs = ($segs - floor($segs)) * 1000;
        $segs = floor($segs);

        return 
            (empty($dias) ? "" : $dias . "d ") . 
            (empty($horas) ? "" : $horas . "h ") . 
            (empty($minutos) ? "" : $minutos . "m ") . 
            $segs . "s " .
            $microsegs . "ms";
    }

}
```

Uso:

```
$th = new TemporizacaoHelper();
<..código sendo medido..>
$echo $th->tempo();
$th->iniciar(); // se for o caso
<..código sendo medido..>
$echo $th->tempo();

// resultado: 4d 17h 34m 57s 0.00095367431640625ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar XHProf (http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).
Originalmente ele foi desenvolvido pelo facebook, eu acho uma excelente ferramenta e tem uma interface bem amigável.

Answer (score -1):

Achei esse fórum quando eu estava tendo o mesmo problema de medir minhas funções, requisições, instanciamentos e tudo mais. Buscando encontrar uma função ou classe simples vi nas repostas acima  boas idéias, e a partir delas, pude fazer alguns aprimoramentos.

Assim criei uma classe que segue a idéia do jquery Quinit, é bem simples, mas cumpre o mínimo de ***medir tempo de execução***, o ***número de interações*** e um ***assert true e false***.

Se vc estiver familiarizado com a ferramenta javascript QUnit, não terá dificuldade em utilizar essa classe php.

```
<?php
#Tester.php 

header ( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
error_reporting ( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_startup_errors', TRUE );
ini_set ( "display_errors", TRUE );
ini_set ( "default_charset", TRUE );

class Tester 
{
    private static $offset = 0.000007;
    private static $success = array ( "#0A0", "rgba(0,190,0,0.1)" );
    private static $error = array ( "#C00", "rgba(190,0,0,0.1)" );

    private static $status = false;
    private static $name = null;
    private static $msg = null;
    private static $repeat = 1;

    private static $timeOfTest = 0;
    private static $timeOfEachTest = 0;

    private static function reset ( ) 
    {
        self::$status = false;
        self::$name = null;
        self::$msg = null;
        self::$repeat = 1;
        self::$timeOfTest = 0;
        self::$timeOfEachTest = 0;

    }

    private static function assert ( ) 
    { 
        return "Tester";
    }

    public static function ok ( bool $status = false, string $msg = null ): bool
    {
        self::$msg = $msg;
        return self::$status = $status;
    }

    private static function inner ( ) 
    {   
        $set = ( self::$status !== false ) ? self::$success : self::$error;

        $title = '<span><b>'.self::$name.' </b><small>'.round ( self::$timeOfEachTest, 6 ).'ms <sub>( x'.self::$repeat.' )</sub></small> </span>';
        $time = '<span style="float: right;text-align: right; rigth: 0;"><b>Tempo total: '.round ( ( self::$timeOfTest / 1000 ), 2 ).'s <small> ( '. round ( self::$timeOfTest, 4 ).'ms )</b></small></span>';
        $msg = '<div style="font-size: 10pt;">'.self::$msg.'</div>';

        echo '<div style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 10pt; display: block; border: solid 1px '.$set [ 0 ].'; background-color: '.$set [ 1 ].'; padding: 5px; margin: 2px 0;"><div style="display: block; margin-bottom: 4px; border-bottom: solid 1px '.$set [ 1 ].'; padding-bottom: 3px; width:100%;">'.$title.$time.'</div>'.$msg.'</div>';
    }  

    private static function sum ( array $array = null ): float
    {
        return array_reduce ( $array, function ( $previous, $item ) {
            return $previous += $item;
        } );
    }

    public static function on ( string $name = null, Closure $fn = null, int $repeat = 1 ) 
    {
        self::reset ( );

        if ( is_string ( $name ) && $fn instanceof Closure && is_numeric ( self::$repeat ) ) {

            self::$name = $name;
            self::$repeat = $repeat;

            $timeOfFunctions = array ( );
            $init = microtime ( 1 );

            for ( $i = 0; $i < self::$repeat; $i++ ) {
                $time = microtime ( 1 );
                $fn ( self::assert ( ) );
                array_push ( $timeOfFunctions, ( ( microtime ( 1 ) - $time ) * 1000 ) );
            };

            $timeOfExec = ( ( ( microtime ( 1 ) - $init ) - self::$offset ) * 1000 );
            $timeOfEachExec = ( $timeOfExec / self::$repeat );

            $totalOfFunctions = self::sum ( $timeOfFunctions );
            $timeOfEachFunction = ( $totalOfFunctions / count ( $timeOfFunctions ) );

            self::$timeOfTest = ( ( $timeOfExec + $totalOfFunctions ) / 2 );
            self::$timeOfEachTest = ( ( $timeOfEachExec + $timeOfEachFunction ) / 2 );

        } else {
            self::$name = ( empty ( self::$name ) ) ? "Error!" : self::$name;
            self::$msg = " Erro de Sintaxe. Favor verificar os argumentos de entrada do teste.";
        };

        self::inner ( );
    } 
}

#Tester::on ( "test 1", function ( $assert ) { $assert::ok ( true, "msg" ); }, 1000 );
```

O Uso é simples, pois optei por iniciar toda a classe por métodos estáticos, evitei criar a instância concreta da classe para não interferir na performance, caso hajam muitos testes, mas isso é optativo se usar o instanciamento da classe no padrão Singleton. Segue um modelo de Uso abaixo.

```
Tester::on ( "nome do teste", function ( $assert ) {
    $assert::ok ( true, "descrição do teste" );
}, 1 );
```

[image: Exemplo do tester rodando]

Minhas recomendações de uso são:

- A classe é simples, o que justifica seu uso em casos simples.
- O jeito certo de usar a classe é criando um arquivo de teste unitário, jamais usar a classe nos arquivos do software.
- O arquivo desta classe deve ser **o primeiro a ser incluído** no arquivo de teste, pois contém a função header, o que pode ocasionar em erros se assim não proceder
- O método estático **::on ( )** é responsável por iniciar o teste, o que o torna obrigatório.
- O método **::on ( )** segue a seguinte convenção:
  `::on ( string $nomeDoTeste, function $funcaoDeTeste, number $numeroDeIterações )`.   Assim o primeiro argumento é uma **string** que especifica o nome do teste, o segundo argumento é uma **função anônima** que valida o teste e o terceiro argumento é o **número** de vezes que se roda o mesmo teste.
- A função anônima recebe um parâmetro "assert" que é a classe **Tester**, essa por sua vez disponibiliza o médoto estático **::ok ( )**.
- O método estático **::ok ( )** é responsável por validar o teste e descrever a ação, por isso ele recebe dois argumentos, ***o primeiro deve ser do tipo bool***, que certifica se o teste passou e ***o segundo do tipo string*** que descreve a ação testada como abaixo.

  ```
  $assert::ok ( true, "descrição do teste" );
  ```