# Qual possui um desempenho melhor? For ou Foreach+Range?

Tags: php, desempenho, loop, foreach

Das duas formas abaixo, qual possui um desempenho melhor?

1. `For`:

   ```
   for( $x=1; $x < 31; $x++ )
      echo $x . PHP_EOL;
   ```
2. `Foreach` + `range`:

   ```
   foreach( range(1,30) as $x )
      echo $x . PHP_EOL;
   ```

Sei que a diferença será provavelmente em milissegundos, mas vale a pena o estudo uma vez que em uma aplicação com grande tráfego esses milissegundos podem fazer diferença.

Se houver uma terceira forma de desempenho ainda melhor, por favor aponte.

Comment: Sem nem executar o código, eu diria que o primeiro fragmento é mais rápido, já que não precisa criar uma array, nem acessar os valores dela.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O [`for`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php) possuí um desempenho *ligeiramente* melhor sobre o [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), neste caso porque a [função `range`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) retorna um *array* de elementos resultantes da iteração e acessa cada item deste.

Veja um comparativo entre as duas formas num *loop* de *350000* iterações:

```php
function bench($func) {
    $tempo = -microtime(true);
    $func();
    $tempo += microtime(true);
    return number_format($tempo, 4);
}

function func1() {
    for($x = 1; $x < 350000; $x++) echo $x;
}

function func2() {
    foreach(range(1, 350000) as $x) echo $x;
}

$tempoDecorrido = bench('func1');
echo "\n For => Tempo decorrido: {$tempoDecorrido} segundos \n";

$tempoDecorrido = bench('func2');
echo "\n Foreach => Tempo decorrido: {$tempoDecorrido} segundos \n";
```

Resultado:

```all
12345678910....
For => Tempo decorrido: 0.48403 segundos
1234567891011....
Foreach => Tempo decorrido: 0.74004 segundos
```

O resultado pode ser *bastante* diferente dependendo do ambiente de execução. Outras formas para se medir o desempenho de códigos no PHP podem ser vistos na questão [**Como medir a performance de códigos em PHP?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1673/6454)

Pergunta relacionada: [**Até que ponto a otimização prematura é um problema?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/6454)

### Alternativa

A partir do PHP 5.5 foi introduzido o suporte aos [***Geradores***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.php), a ideia por trás dos *geradores* é que uma função não retorna um valor único, mas sim uma sequência de valores em vez disso, onde cada valor é emitido *um a um*. Em outras palavras, *geradores* permitem implementar [*Iteradores*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.iterations.php) de um modo mais simples e sem a complexidade da implementação de uma classe que implementa a interface `Iterator`.

Uma vantagem de utilizar *geradores* é a possibilidade de iterar sobre um conjunto de dados **sem colocá-los na memória de uma só vez**, algo que a [função `range()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) não faz. Quando a função *gerador* é executada, é retornado por meio da palavra reservada [`yield`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield) (um tipo de `return` *especial*), uma *chave/valor* e, quando solicitado o próximo elemento do `Iterator`, a função *gerador* continua de onde parou o último `yield`.

Segue um outro comparativo, agora num *loop* de *600000* iterações, e comparando também uma função *gerador*, o `xrange`:

```php
function bench($func){
    $tempo = -microtime(true);
    echo $func();
    $tempo += microtime(true);
    return number_format($tempo, 4);
}

function xrange($inicio, $fim, $passo = 1) {
    for ($i = $inicio; $i <= $fim; $i += $passo) yield $i;
}
function func1(){
    for($x = 1; $x < 600000; $x++) echo $x;
}
function func2(){
    foreach(xrange(1, 600000) as $x) echo $x;
}
function func3(){
    foreach(range(1, 600000) as $x) echo $x;
}
$tempo = bench('func1');
echo "\n For: {$tempo} \n";
$tempo = bench('func2');
echo "\n xrange: {$tempo} \n";
$tempo = bench('func3');
echo "\n range: {$tempo} \n";
```

O resultado foi:

```
1234567891011121314151...
For: 1.0861
123456789101112131415161...
xrange: 2.5801
12345678910111213141516171...
range: 2.7602
```

Utilizar um ou outro, pouco irá interferir no desempenho, use o [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) em situações onde é necessário somente *varrer* a *array*, o [`for`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php), para situações onde seja preciso trabalhar com o *índice* dos elementos, por exemplo, acessar elementos anteriores ou posteriores na iteração atual. Já os [*Geradores*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.php), use em situações onde seja necessário contornar os limites de memória.

Answer (score 8):

Minha opinião pessoal é usar o que faz sentido no contexto. A diferença de tempo vai ser mínima na maioria dos casos.

A grande coisa a observar é:

```
for( $x=1; $x < 31; $x++ )
```

Isso é um loop caro, uma vez que ele chama a contagem em cada iteração. Contudo se você não está fazendo isso, eu não acho que realmente importará ...

Quanto ao, `foreach` no segundo caso seria "equivalente" a:

```
$It->rewind();
while ($it->valido()) {
    $key = $it->key(); // Se estiver usando $key => sintaxe $value
    $value = $it->current();

    // conteúdo do loop aqui

    $it->next();
}
```

Só em ver, já percebe-se que é mais complexo que o primeiro.

Existem formas mais rápidas para fazer uma iteração, e isso depende do problema.

Vamos simular uma corrida entre o `FOR` e `FOREACH`:

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($x = 1; $x < 31; $x++) {}
echo "Concluído em", microtime(true) - $start, "Segundos \n"

$start = microtime(true);
for (range(1,30) as $x ) {}
echo "Concluído em", microtime(true) - $start, "Segundos \n"
```

Os resultados podem variar dependendo do ambiente de execução.

Outras comparações:

```
$a = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 31; $i++) {
    $a[] = $i;
}

$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $a[$k] = $v + 1;
}
echo "Concluído em", microtime(true) - $start, "Segundos \n";

$start = microtime (true);
foreach (($a as $k => &$v) {
    $v = $v + 1;
}
echo "Concluído em", microtime (true) - $start, "Segundos \n";

$start = microtime (true);
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {}
echo "Concluído em", microtime (true) - $start, "Segundos \n";

$start = microtime (true);
foreach ($a as $k => &$v) {}
echo "Concluído em", microtime (true) - $start, "Segundos \n";
```

Os resultados:

```
Concluído em:  0.00161790847778  Segundos 
Concluído em:  0.00043797492981  Segundos 
Concluído em:  0.000297069549561 Segundos 
Concluído em:  0.000345945358276 Segundos
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php)