# FOREACH ou FOR?

Tags: php

Em relação a desempenho do código o que é mais vantajoso, usar `foreach` ou `for`?

Exemplo:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

//assim
foreach($array as $value)
{
}

//ou assim
$count = count($array);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
}
```

Comment: A resposta dessa outra pergunta semelhante talvez lhe ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63005/qual-possui-um-desempenho-melhor-for-ou-foreachrange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, sobre desempenho em relação a loops o mais recomendado pra percorrer arrays é o **foreach** pois o desempenho dele e muito superior ao do *for* tradicional, você pode conferir isso usando uma função do php, *microtime()*, o *foreach* foi feito quase que exclusivamente para percorrer coleções de dados como o array. Porém nem tudo são flores com o *foreach* você só vai poder percorrer os elementos numa unica direção, ou seja, crescente do inicio ao fim da coleção, ja com o *for* você tem a **flexibilidade** de percorrer do inicio ao fim e vice-versa.
Resumindo você vai usar o *for* ou o *foreach* dependendo da aplicação não visando somente o desempenho.

```
<?php

$n = array(2,1,4,6,45,7,45,3,23,465,67,77,88,234,432,5566,309,44,9,323,545,5656,6768,667,32,239,122,298);
$tot = count($n);

$t = microtime();

for($i = 0; $i < $tot; $i++) {}

echo "tempo do for:     <br />",microtime() - $t,' segundos<br /><br />';


$t2 = microtime();
foreach($n as $v) {}

echo "tempo do foreach: <br />", microtime() - $t2,' segundos';


?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.