# Diferença de desempenho do for simples e o for iterador

Tags: java, android, desempenho, for

Tenho uma lista de clientes e em determinada tela o usuário pode fazer uma busca e editar os clientes da lista que é bem extensa, comparando esses dois exemplos qual seria o melhor para trabalhar?

#### Exemplo 1:

```
for (int i = 0, tamI = listAll.size(); i< tamI;i++)
           if (listAll.get(i).getNome().toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
                listResult.add(listAll.get(i));
```

#### Exemplo 2:

```
for (Cliente item : listAll)
            if(item.getNome().toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
                listResult.add(item);
```

Comment: Relacionada : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63005/qual-possui-um-desempenho-melhor-for-ou-foreachrange

Comment: [Há diferença entre informar o tamanho na condição do laço ou fora dele?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152521/91)

Comment: Este site é bacana para compara métodos Javascript/Jquery : https://jsperf.com/

Comment: @Bruno mas não tem nenhum código Javascript/Jquery aqui!

Comment: Eu estou usando o segundo exemplo, por ser uma implementação da linguagem acredito que ela seja otimizada para essas situações

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende um pouco do que é esse `ListAll`, pode ser vários tipos de estrutura, cada um com um comprometimento de complexidade diferente. Tem coleção que o **cálculo** do `size()` pode ser enorme e uma iteração pode ser absurdamente mais rápida. Mas considerando que o `size()` tem complexidade O(1) baixo a diferença deve ser bem pouca, muitas vezes variando de acordo com outras circunstâncias.

Sendo assim, use a estrutura de controle de fluxo mais legível, que mostre melhor a intenção e que evita mais erros deveria ser a preferida, portanto a que usa o iterador (*for each*) seria melhor.

Pode ser que algum caso tenha performance melhor o `for` simples, mas teria que analisar caso a caso. Não presuma que sabe qual será mais rápido, pode quebrar a cara. Existem otimizações que podem dar resultado diferente do intuitivo. E pode mudar de acordo com a versão do compilador ou do *framework*.

Comment: ListAll tem um media uns 3000 registros ou mais

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost editei pra mostrar que o tamanho não importa